# Azure distributed cache for IaaS VMs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-caching

Is it possible to use Azure shared cache service from load-balanced IaaS VMs? Does it exists at all? I can't seem to find caching service in management portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IaaS with Windows Server, you may want to explore using [Server AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). This gives you dedicated resources, co-hosted in your Azure VM's at a lower latency and without the quota's imposed by the shared caching service.

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at the [Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cache/) that has just been launched. It supports distributed caching from IaaS VMs. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386094.aspx/) to find out if you need this.